# Inner join 4 columns with different server .., different database ., and different table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, inner-join

I have 3 server:

```
 ECPAYSERV2 
 POSSQLSERVER 
 ECPAYSERV1
```

3 databases

```
 ECPNWEB
 ECPNPOS
 ECPNDB
```

and 3 tables

```
 account
 branch
 terminal
```

I have also finish to link the server :

```
 ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.account
 POSSQLSERVER.ECPNPOS.dbo.branch
 ECPAYSERV1.ECPNDB.dbo.terminal
```

The fields that should be seen would be the following

```
 AccountID = ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.account.(accntid)
 BranchID = ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.branch.(branchid)
 TID = ECPAYSERV1.ECPNDB.dbo.terminal.(TID)
 Store # = POSSQLSERVER.ECPNPOS.dbo.branch.(Storeno)
 Store name = ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.account.(accountholder)
 Branch name = ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.brachn.(branchname) ,  POSSQLSERVER.ECPNPOS.dbo.branch.(branchname) , ECPAYSERV1.ECPNDB.dbo.terminal.(retail_store_code)
```

**The data enclosed with parethesis are the columns.,**

To be more clear of all this are the columns in the table..

Table : Account

```
 |Accntid|managedby|Accountholder|Description|AccountType|ContactPerson|ContactNumber|EmailAddress|
```

Table : Branch

```
 |BranchID|BranchName|AccountID|StoreNo|Description|Status|
```

Table : Terminal

```
 |TerminalID|TID|retail_store_code|t_distributor_code|
```

All I want is to Get this output with RIGHT data ..

```
 |accntid|accountholder|tid|storeno|branchname|branchid|
```

This is what I tried for but not getting the RIGHT output

```
 SELECT account.accntid,account.accountholder,terminal.tid,branch.storeno,branch.branchname,branch1.branchid
 FROM ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.account as account 
 INNER JOIN POSSQLSERVER.ECPNPOS.dbo.branch as branch
  ON account.accntid=branch.branchid 
 INNER JOIN ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.branch as branch1
  ON account.accntid=branch1.branchid
 INNER JOIN ECPAYSERV1.ECPNDB.dbo.terminal as terminal 
  ON account.accntid=terminal.tid
```

Please help me about This matter Thanks :(

Comment: at first look: you are joining pk with pk when you need joining pk with fk

Comment: @tschmit007 so what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    account.accntid, account.accountholder, terminal.tid, branch.storeno, branch.branchname, branch1.branchid
FROM 
    ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.account as account 
    INNER JOIN POSSQLSERVER.ECPNPOS.dbo.branch as branch
        ON account.accntid=branch.AccountID 
    INNER JOIN ECPAYSERV2.ECPNWEB.dbo.branch as branch1
        ON account.accntid=branch1.AccountID
    INNER JOIN ECPAYSERV1.ECPNDB.dbo.terminal as terminal 
        ON account.accntid=terminal.???
```

the ??? is not correct, but it is not clear which column of terminal is a FK for account.